# Can't run mysql server on xampp

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I just installed xampp server on Windows XP machine and can't run mysql. Here is a it's error log file text:

```
151225 10:41:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
151225 10:41:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-creating-innodb.html
151225 10:41:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
151225 10:41:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
151225 10:41:21 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
151225 10:41:21 [ERROR] Aborting

151225 10:41:21 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

Steps I have tried include: removing lblogfile0 and lblogfile1 files from data directory, removing innoDB directory path from mysql config file. Does anyone have any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Re-installing the **Xampp**.
Check port are clear and open

Answer (score 0):

From XAMPP [**Windows Help**](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html)

Microsoft delivers a better firewall with service pack 2 (SP2), which starts automatically. This firewall now blocks the necessary ports 80 (http) and 443 (https) and Apache can't start.

The fast solution:

Disable the Microsoft firewall with the toolbar and try to start XAMPP onces more. The better solution is to define an exception within the security center.

```
The following ports are used for basic functionality:

Apache (HTTP): Port 80
Apache (WebDAV): Port 81
Apache (HTTPS): Port 443
MySQL: Port 3306
FileZilla (FTP): Port 21
FileZilla (Admin): Port 14147
Mercury (SMTP): Port 25
Mercury (POP3): Port 110
Mercury (IMAP): Port 143
Mercury (HTTP): Port 2224
Mercury (Finger): Port 79
Mercury (PH): Port 105
Mercury (PopPass): Port 106
Tomcat (AJP/1.3): Port 8009
Tomcat (HTTP): Port 8080
```

Comment: Sorry But Apache does start.

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems that InnoDB engine is failing to allocate the datafiles. Best way would be to uninstall and reinstall. Also check which version is compatible with Windows XP, since the newest one isn't (you need 1.8.2).